# Varistor derating chart reading

Tags: surge-protection

I am studying TDK document about varistor selection but I cannot understand how to read the derating curve. The Imax I got is different from that mentioned in the [document](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/531308/8cd06030e8ddf20bd381c1e8917f0e9c/siov-applications.pdf).
In Figure 20 of the application note, the reading is 48 A (Imax) but my reading is about 70 A @tr = 386us.

What did I get wrong here?

---

Thanks all.

This is my first reading too. But how to understand "can be deduced"?
How to decide surge current when select varistors?

Comment: At first glance my reading is more like 7 A @ tr = 386us for 15X.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with John D and don't understand at first glance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If we look up the [current datasheet](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/70/db/var/SIOV_Leaded_StandarD.pdf) for the part in question, we get this graph:

[image]

Which is a bit more in line with the app note (~65A), but still significantly off. What a dog's breakfast. Checking the older Epcos datasheets (and possibly there was another company name before Epcos was acquired in 2008, varistors are really old technology) is left as an exercise.